# I'm trying to restore a database in SQL Server Express 2019 but the restore dialog freezes when I click the "..." icon to choose a backup file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2019

This wasn't happening earlier but then a SQL Server update installed and SQL Server restarted, and now I can't restore any databases... I tried restoring the database via the SQL command interface:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\MyDatabase.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

but then I get this error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\MyDatabase.bak'. Operating system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I checked that the backup file exists; I'm not sure why I'm getting this error...

Comment: Are you sure it's on the root of C? That's bad practice, hence my question (to have it on C period). And C: would be C: on the DB server, not your local machine unless that's where your instance is installed. If you are certain, right click on your DB > Tasks > Restore > Database and see if you can browse to that .bak file.

Comment: I am restoring to localhost. Now for some reason I'm able to choose the file, but SSMS crashes when I go to the options page on the restore dialog to tell it use the "with replace" option...

Comment: I have to agree, i very much doubt that your SQL Server instance has access to the root of C, and personally, I don't think it *should*. Put the file in a location it *does* have access to.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why SSMS would crash... maybe a memory issue. Have you tried rebooting? It sounds like your original question is resolved, though.

Comment: Make sure the user of `SQL Server Service` has access to folder and the `.bak` file (sometimes inheritance permissions would not available on backup files when it's copied from other location)